# shutil.unpack_archive and ziplib both return FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, unzip, shutil

I'm trying to unzip some zip files in Python:

```
print(f"Unzipping:\n{os.getcwd()}\\{constants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER}\\{case_number}\\{username_hostname}.zip")
 # with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{os.getcwd()}\\{constants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER}\\{case_number}\\{username_hostname}.zip") as z: 
#     z.extractall(path=f"{os.getcwd()}\\{constants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER}\\{case_number}\\{username_hostname}") 
shutil.unpack_archive(f"{os.getcwd()}\\{constants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER}\\{case_number}\\{username_hostname}.zip",
                       f"{os.getcwd()}\\{constants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER}\\{case_number}\\{username_hostname}") 
print(f"Unzipped:\n{os.getcwd()}\\{constants.DOWNLOADS_FOLDER}\\{case_number}\\{username_hostname}")
```

It works for most of the zip files (`case_number` being the same, and `username_hostname` being different), but I got only 2~3 files which always return:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\current_workdirectory\\downloads\\case_number\\username_hostname\\path\\OmniDesk \\OmniDesk.pdf'
```

... or ...

```
'D:\\current_workdirectory\\downloads\\case_number\\username_hostname\\path\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\path\\OCT 11 to 16th \\2022-10-11.xlsx'
```

I tried to manually unzip the file (in Windows) and it works fine.

I do notice a strange space at the end of these files' parent foldername, and when I manually unzip the archive, the space is NOT in the foldername of the unpacked archive.

Is this what caused the problem?

---

`case_number` and `username_hostname` is created from `sys.argv`:

```
case_number = sys.argv[1]  # e.g., XXX-YYY
username_hostname = sys.argv[2]   # e.g., johnsmith_PC12345
```

---

printout:

```
DEBUG: This is case_number -->F23-003<--
Unzipping:
D:\path\F23-003\username_hostname.zip
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
...
```

---

I saw a discussion on cpython' github repo: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/94018#issuecomment-1160309581

But, according to the repo, this issue should has been solved: `gvanrossum pushed a commit to gvanrossum/cpython that referenced this issue on Jul 1, 2022`

I'm using Python 3.11.1

Comment: `case_number` must have a space at the end.  Show us how that variable is created.

Comment: `case_number` is created from `sys.argv`, which will not contain any space, because I manually input the argument in commandline.

Comment: We would need to see the whole code in order to find the problem.  This code is not enough to tell.

Comment: The space is in the final directory name, so it has to be `case_number`. Are you modifying that variable anywhere else in the code?  Anyway, as a debugging step, add this print statement before calling unpack_archive(): `print(f' This is case_number -->{case_number}<--')`

Comment: I think, the space is probably in some folder in the archive, but I don't know where does it come from, as I can't see it after manual unzipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that Python 3.11.1 hasn't included this commit (mentioned in the question) yet, so I edited Python's built-in `zipfile` myself:

(line 1689, original)

```
arcname = (x.rstrip('.') for x in arcname.split(pathsep))
```

to...

(line 1689)

```
arcname = (x.rstrip(' .') for x in arcname.split(pathsep))
```

... which solved the problem.

So, if anyone encounters the same problem, please copy Python's built-in `zipfile.py`, edit it as described above, and put it into your project folder.

By importing the edited `zipfile.py`, you can overwrite Python's built-in troublesome `zipfile.py`.